# right continuity of martingale constructed by $X_t=E[X|\mathcal{F}_t]$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

$X\in L_1$ is a random variable, and $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a filtration satisfying the usual conditions, so could we find a version of martingale defined by $X_t=E[X|\mathcal{F}_t]$. I think the answer is yes, for I have seen this result in class, but could someone provide a proof for this? Many thanks!

Comment: Is $t$ continuous or discrete?

Comment: $t$ is continous

Comment: That being the case, I fixed the title to replace n by t.

Comment: @Higgs88 Sorry... I haven't had to deal with continuous-time processes in several years (my work is combinatorial probability), and I'm afraid I'm out of practice!

Comment: There is this famous proposition: see for example Theorem 6.27 in Foundations of modern probability by Kallenberg: For any $\mathcal{F}$-submartingale $X$ on $\mathbb{R}_+$ with restriction $Y$ to $\mathbb{Q}_+$ we have: if $\mathcal{F}$ is right continuous, then $X$ has a RCLL version iff $t\mapsto E[X_t]$ is right continuous. (this is trivially true for martingales.